# How do I prevent SQLite database locks?

Tags: locking, sqlite

From SQLite FAQ I've known that:

> Multiple processes can have the same database open at the same time.
>   Multiple processes can be doing a `SELECT` at the same time. But only
>   one process can be making changes to the database at any moment in
>   time, however.

So, as far as I understand I can:
1) Read db from multiple threads (`SELECT`)
2) Read db from multiple threads (`SELECT`) and write from single thread (`CREATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`)

But, I read about [**Write-Ahead Logging**](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) that  provides more concurrency as *readers do not block writers and a writer does not block readers*. Reading and writing can proceed concurrently.

Finally, I've got completely muddled when I found [it](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DatabaseIsLocked&t=1292363538), when specified:

> Here are other reasons for getting an SQLITE_LOCKED error:
>
> - Trying to `CREATE` or `DROP` a table or index while a `SELECT` statement is
>     still pending.
> - Trying to write to a table while a `SELECT` is active on that same table.
> - Trying to do two `SELECT` on the same table at the same time in a
>     multithread application, if sqlite is not set to do so.
> - fcntl(3,F_SETLK call on DB file fails. This could be caused by an NFS locking
>     issue, for example. One solution for this issue, is to mv the DB away,
>     and copy it back so that it has a new Inode value

So, I would like to clarify for myself, it is necessary to avoid the lock? Can I read and write at the same time from two different threads? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That page you linked, besides being quite old, talks about accesses from the same process through the same database connection (or through multipe connections in [shared cache mode](http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html), which you should not use).

When not in WAL mode, multiple connections can read from the same database, but a writing transaction is exclusive, i.e., no other readers or writers are allowed.

In WAL mode, a writer and readers do not block each other, but there is still only one writer allowed.

Comment: What is wrong with shared cache mode? I was able to get multiple python threads in the same process to write to a table with it via a [joblb Parallel for loop](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html). I had locking issues until a set `isolation_level=None` though. Without shared cache mode, how do i share instances between threads?

Comment: The documentation describes the disadvantages. It is especially dangerous if you don't know how to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: Coming in very late to the party, but this link is useful. http://manski.net/2012/10/sqlite-performance/